# ASP .NET MVC and ASPX files Hosting issue on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have a ASP .NET MVC 1.0 application which contains few ASPX files located instead Reports folder (located on root) of application.

My Global.asax contains following lines:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}" );

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",  // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",               // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = ""
            }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

But when I try to access following URL,

http://xx/Reports/SomeASPXPage.aspx

I get 404 (file not found error).

What I am missing in configuration?

JFYI: IIS 6 is running on Win2K3 box with wild-card mapping enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

There is no issue with ASP .NET MVC configuration; Reporting services was over-riding the Reports directory of the web-app and at host/Reports SQL Server reporting was taking over.

Answer (score 1):

Google MVC and II6.  There are some things you need to include in the global.asax file to get the routing to run under IIS6.

[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - but I have already googled; if you see my question; I am Mixing .ASPX files and MVC controllers. MVC is functioning properly, the issue with calling Reports.aspx file which is located inside Reports folder.